# MSSQL temp table returns all rows when using IN subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I recently stumbled upon this example. Why does query return all rows when using non-defined column on temp table "id". This only works for id and it only works when using IN subquery.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
( Id INT)

INSERT INTO @test
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3

SELECT * FROM @test

SELECT 1 AS 'myid'
INTO #tmpId

--Returns one rows - OK
SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id in (SELECT myId FROM #tmpId)
--Returns all rowns - WHY
SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM #tmpId)
--ERROR - no column - OK
SELECT * FROM @test WHERE id in (SELECT asdf FROM #tmpId)
--ERROR - no column - OK
SELECT id FROM #tmpId

DROP TABLE #tmpId
```

Comment: You are comparing the I'd column to itself in the second query so always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* use table aliases when you have multiple tables.  The first query should be written as:

```
SELECT t.* FROM @test t WHERE t.id in (SELECT tt.myid FROM #tmpId tt)
```

This does what you want.

If you write the second query as:

```
SELECT t.* FROM @test t WHERE t.id in (SELECT tt.id FROM #tmpId tt)
```

You will get an error.  Your version is interpreted as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.* FROM @test t WHERE t.id in (SELECT t.id FROM #tmpId tt)
```

That is not what you want.  It is equivalent to:

```
SELECT t.* FROM @test t WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second query you are comparing the Id column to itself as doesn't exist in inner table, so always true